# Hover over text effect

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML & CSS, but here goes none the less.

I have put together this bit of code to make the text inside my navbar glow up upon hover:

```
li:hover {
    color: orange;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

However, as soon as I remove my cursor from the text, the glow instantly disappears instead of gradually decreasing like when it lights up.

Does anyone know what I have to add in order to achieve this effect?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Right now the transition only exits when hovering. So when you're cursor moves away the `li` doesn't have any transitions set to it. Move the transition part of your css to a regular `li{}` selector and you'll be golden! good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the transition to your `li`

```
li {
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

You need to set transitions for all states. As with `li:hover`, you told the CSS to transition everything transition-able when the element is hovered. Here you tell it to transition to its normal state after the interaction as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/L5s2h1k7/

Comment: @HSmith Added a jsfiddle example for you to see the effect

Answer (score 0):

Define the *default* properties of **li** before the *hover* properties.

```
li {
/*Default properties + animation*/
}

li:hover {
/*OnHover Properties + animation*/
}
```

Now it will animate as you wanted it to.

Comment: It would be helpful to show the appropriate CSS statement(s) to help people understanding your answer

Comment: @StephenReindl Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can also add a `background:#0070ba;` color to it.

```
li {
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
li:hover {
    background:#0070ba;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```